# Contribution page receipt (date and time)

Tags: civicontribute

My contribution page receipt is showing the wrong date and time.

I submitted the page at 11.30 on 1st August 2016, but the receipt to my email states '8th, 2016 1:01AM'

Update: Further submissions show that '8th, 2016 1:01AM' is always shown. I am using a webform to submit the details.

Everything else is correct, just this. Any ideas please?

CIVICRM 4.5.8
Drupal

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: I've been there - seen that! Trying to remember what caused it and most importantly how it got solved.

Comment: any luck remembering?

Comment: I've got it narrowed down to the site we noticed this on - it was also a webform integration - but can't reproduce it;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been there; seen this - exactly this - but it got resolved - likely during a 4.6 minor version upgrade - before we had a chance to debug it ourselves.

I highly recommend you upgrade from 4.5.x for many other reasons than the receipting.

Comment: Thank you, yes we are upgrading to 4.6 in a week so finders crossed.